# Swift metatype (Type, self)

Tags: swift

I am trying to understand : "`self, dynamicType, Type`". I have this code :

```
class SomeClass {}

let cls : SomeClass.Type = SomeClass.self
let cls2 : SomeClass = SomeClass()
```

Are `cls` and `cls2` the same thing ?

Can someone give some detail about the differences ? Thanks

Comment: No, they are not the same: `cls` is of type `SomeClass.Type`, whereas `cls2` is of type `SomeClass`. Just try adding a single property to your class, and you'll notice you cannot access it from `cls`, whereas you naturally can from `cls2`. Also note the difference when testing meta-type comparison, `SomeClass.self === cls` vs `SomeClass.self === cls2.dynamicType` (both `true`).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, `cls` and `cls2` are different things. The easiest way to understand the difference will be to extend your example like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    class func doIt() {
        print("I'm a class method. I belong to my type.")
    }

    func doItOnlyIfInstanceOfThisType() {
        print("I'm a instance method. I belong to my type instance.")
    }
}
```

And now let's take your `cls`:

```
let cls : SomeClass.Type = SomeClass.self
cls.doIt()
```

That will print `I'm a class method. I belong to my type.`. But you cannot invoke this:

```
cls.doItOnlyIfInstanceOfThisType() // causes a compilation error, PRO TIP: actually you can use this method as a func property, but I'll add the explanation for this later
```

Let's take your `cls2`. The only visible method of it is `doItOnlyIfInstanceOfThisType` because it's an instance method (of this type).

```
let cls2 : SomeClass = SomeClass()
cls2.doItOnlyIfInstanceOfThisType()
```

So the difference between them is that `cls` is a type and `cls2` is an instance of this type.

**A little bit more knowledge about why SomeClass.self and SomeClass()?**

The type of a class also exists in memory (it has for example its own methods), as a singleton representing the Type (not an instance of this type - that's something different).
If you call `self` on a Type like this `SomeClass.self` you will get a singleton instance representing the `SomeClass` Type.

`SomeClass()` invokes the `init()` method of `SomeClass`, a constructor that creates an instance of `SomeClass`.

**PRO Tip**

You can manipulate a Type instance function (like closures/blocks in ObjC). It's a generated class method. But you must pass an instance of the type that you take this method from as an argument, like this:

```
let myFunc :()->() = cls.doItOnlyIfInstanceOfThisType(cls2)
myFunc()
```

Comment: Great explanation! Especially about singleton (didn't know that). Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

A metatype type refers to the type of any type, including class types, structure types, enumeration types, and protocol types.

You can use the postfix self expression to access a type as a value. For example, `SomeClass.self` returns `SomeClass` itself, **not an instance of `SomeClass`**. And `SomeProtocol.self` returns `SomeProtocol` itself, not an instance of a type that conforms to `SomeProtocol` at runtime. You can use a `dynamicType` expression with an instance of a type to access that instance’s dynamic, runtime type as a value, as the following example shows:

```
class SomeBaseClass {
    class func printClassName() {
        print("SomeBaseClass")
    }
}
class SomeSubClass: SomeBaseClass {
    override class func printClassName() {
        print("SomeSubClass")
    }
}
let someInstance: SomeBaseClass = SomeSubClass()
someInstance.dynamicType.printClassName()
// prints "SomeSubClass"
```

**The compile-time type of `someInstance` is `SomeBaseClass`,
the runtime type of `someInstance` is `SomeSubClass`**

You can use the identity operators (=== and !==) to test whether an instance’s runtime type is the same as its compile-time type.

```
if someInstance.dynamicType === SomeBaseClass.self {
    print("The dynamic type of someInstance is SomeBaseCass")
} else {
    print("The dynamic type of someInstance isn't SomeBaseClass")
}
```

More detail -> The Swift Programming Language: [Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html)

#### Swift 3.0:

`.dynamicType` is deprecated, you should use `type(of:)` to get its meta type:

```
type(of: someInstance).printClassName()
```

Comment: Do you mean self or Self? hard to understand if you guys don't stick to the proper casing

Comment: @thibautnoah all above is `self`