# Metatype of Metatype

Tags: swift

In Swift we are able to write following construction:

```
class SomeClass {}
let metaMetatype: SomeClass.Type.Type = SomeClass.Type.self
```

Here `metaMetatype` does not conform to type `AnyObject` (`SomeClass.Type` does). Construction can be even longer, as long as we wish:

```
let uberMetatype: SomeClass.Type.Type.Type.Type.Type.Type.Type.Type.Type.Type = SomeClass.Type.Type.Type.Type.Type.Type.Type.Type.Type.self
```

Are this constructions have any sense? If `SomeClass.Type.Type` not an object, what is this, and why we able to declare it?

Comment: Well the metatype of a struct (e.g. `String.self`) does not conform to AnyObject either

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but I've attempt to answer (or at least partially answer) your question.

Comment: Hey Shadow, I added a bounty to your question.  Let's see if we can get some more detailed answers

Answer (score 10):

> If `SomeClass.Type.Type` not an object, what is this and why we able to declare it?

I will try to dissect what you're asking.

`SomeClass.Type.Type` is a Metatype of a Metatype.  Metatypes exist in Swift because Swift has types that are not classes.  This is most similar to the Metaclass concept in Objective-C.

[Lexicon.rst](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/Lexicon.rst) in the Swift Open Source Repo has a pretty good explanation:

> metatype
>
> The type of a value representing a type. Greg Parker has a good
>       explanation of [Objective-C's "metaclasses"](http://sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html) because Swift has types
>       that are *not* classes, a more general term is used.
>
> We also sometimes refer to a value representing a type as a "metatype
>       object" or just "metatype", usually within low-level contexts like IRGen
>       and LLDB. This is technically incorrect (it's just a "type object"), but
>       the malapropism happened early in the project and has stuck around.

Why are we able to declare a type of a type of a type... and so on?  Because it's a feature of the language called type metadata:

> type metadata
>
> The runtime representation of a type, and everything you can do with it.
>       Like a `Class` in Objective-C, but for any type.

Note that you can't do something like `NSObject().class` in Swift because `class` is a reserved keyword for the creation of a class.  This is how you would get the type (or class in this case) of an NSObject in Swift:

```
let nsObj = NSObject()
nsObj.classForCoder // NSObject.Type
nsObj.classForKeyedArchiver // NSObject.Type
nsObj.dynamicType // NSObject.Type
```

Note that `nsObj` and `nsObj.self` are identical and represent the instance of that `NSObject`.

I don't see where in the Swift module or open source repo where types allow for `.Type`, but I'm still looking.  It might have to do with the inheritance from SwiftObject, the Objective-C object all Swift classes inherit from (at least on Mac).

Comment: Thank you for answer, it makes things clear a bit. I still don't understand, why `SomeClass` conforms `AnyObject`, `SomeClass.Type` conforms `AnyObject`, but `SomeClass.Type.Type` - not?

Comment: @ShadowOf if I had to guess, it's probably because metatypes of metatypes are of type Any, not AnyObject.  Why, I'm not so sure.  I'm away from my computer right now but will do more investigating when I get back.

Comment: @ShadowOf are you sure `SomeClass.Type` conforms to `AnyObject`?  `SomeClass.Type as! AnyObject` causes a crash for me.

Comment: Yes I'm sure: `let metaMetatype: SomeClass.Type = SomeClass.self; print(metaMetatype as AnyObject)` prints `metaMetatype` description

Answer (score 0):

Type of a class is also represented in memory (it has for example their own methods). It's represented by singleton representing the Type. (It's not an instance of this type - that's something different). If you call self on a Type like this SomeClass.self you will take singleton instance representing the SomeClass Type.

For more info check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35141577/4489420)