# what is T.Type in swift

Tags: swift, generics, types

Can anyone tell me what is `T.Type` when I use `JSONDecoder().decode()`?

I think it is type to decode data what I encoded.

So many example use above method like this:

```
JSONEncoder().decode([People].self, from: data)
```

If I check that method's definition I can see `T.Type`.

I know the generics but what is `T.Type`?

What's the difference between just `T` and `T.Type`?

when we declare some variables, we allocated their types like this

`var someValue: Int`
, not `var someValue: Int.self`

What is the `T.Type` exactly and `Type.self`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift metatype (Type, self)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035185/swift-metatype-type-self)

Comment: `T.Type` is the [metatype type](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID455) for `T`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

- `T.Type` is used in parameters and constraints to mean "the type of the thing itself, not an instance of the thing".

  For example:

  ```
  class Example {
      static var staticVar: String { return "Foo" }
      var instanceVar: String { return "Bar" }
  }

  func printVar(from example: Example) {
      print(example.instanceVar)  // "Bar"
      print(example.staticVar) // Doesn't compile, _Instances_ of Example don't have the property "staticVar"
  }

  func printVar(from example: Example.Type) {
      print(example.instanceVar)  // Doesn't compile, the _Type_ Example doesn't have the property "instanceVar"
      print(example.staticVar) // prints "Foo"
  }
  ```
- You get a reference to a Type's `.Type` (the Type object itself) *at runtime* by calling `TheType.self`.  The syntax `TheType.Type` is used in type declarations and type signatures only to indicate to the compiler the instance vs. type distinction. You can't actually get a reference to, for example, `Int`'s type at runtime or in your function implementations by calling `Int.Type`. You would call `Int.self`
- In the example code `var someValue: Int`, the specific notation `identifier: Type` (in this case, `someValue: Int`) *means* that someValue will be an *instance* of Int. If you wanted someValue to be a reference to the actual type Int, you would write `var someValue: Int.Type = Int.self` Remember that the `.Type` notation is only used when declaring types and type signatures to the compiler, and the `.self` property is used in actual code to retrieve a reference to the type object itself at execution time.
- The reason why `JSONDecoder().decode` requires a parameter of `T.Type` (where `T` conforms to `Decodable`) is because any *type* conforming to `Decodable` has an initializer `init(from decoder: Decoder)`.  The `decode` method will need to call this init method on a *type* that conforms to `Decodable`, not on an *instance* of a type that conforms to `Decodable`. For example:

  ```
  var someString: String = ""
  someString.init(describing: 5) // Not possible, doesn't compile. Can't call an initializer on an _instance_ of String
  var someStringType: String.Type = String.self
  someStringType.init(describing: 5) // Iniitializes a String instance "5"
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your detail and great answer!

Comment: The relevant Apple documentation can be found by Googling "Swift Metatype Type" which should bring you to:  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID455 .

Comment: Excellent answer

Comment: Great answer!! Thank you!