# Instance member 'decode' cannot be used on type 'JSONDecoder'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead

Tags: ios, swift, jsondecoder

I implementing JSONDecoder on to get the JSON data from Wordpress json
my struct is in the other swift file i get this error here's my code. on let article I get the error

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!){ (data,response ,err) in
        guard let data = data else{return}
        let article = JSONDecoder.decode(LatestArticleModel , from: data)

    }.resume()
```

LatestArticleModel.swift

```
struct LatestArticleModel : Decodable {

    var id: Int
    var date: String
    var link: String
    var title_rendered :String
    var author: Int
    var category: Int
    var img_link: String
    var content_rendered: String
    var exerpt_rendered: String


}
```

Comment: `JSONDecoder.decode(LatestArticleModel , from: data)` => `JSONDecoder().decode(LatestArticleModel.self , from: data)`? It's an instance method, not a class method, so you need to use an object. Like `let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder(); jsonDecoder.decode(LatestArticleModel.self, from: data)`, and it's missing `self`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `article` should be declared as:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let article = decoder.decode(LatestArticleModel.self , from: data)
```

If you check the [`decode(_:forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyeddecodingcontainer/2921358-decode), you'll see that it is an instance method (not a static) which means that you should call it via an instance of `JSONDecoder`. Also, the `type` parameters is *T.Type* (the *metatype*), which means that it should be the `self` of the type.

Furthermore: [what is T.Type in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47836341/what-is-t-type-in-swift).

Comment: It's also an instance method, not a class method, there is no `static` in the declaration of it. Because I think the error talk about that, not yet about the missing `self`.

Comment: It worked now thank you. I'll add this this is my code   let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let article = try! decoder.decode(LatestArticleModel.self, from: data)

Answer (score 3):

The issue the compiler error is telling you about is that you are trying to call an instance method on a type instead of an instance of that type. You need to create an instance of `JSONDecoder` and call `decode` on that.

Once you fix that you'll also run into the issue that you need to pass a meta type to the method, so `LatestArticleModel.self` instead of `LatestArticleModel`.

```
let article = JSONDecoder().decode(LatestArticleModel.self, from: data)
```